# WPF Window.Close memory leak

Tags: .net, wpf, memory-leaks

Warning: This is my first 'real' WPF Application.  I'm certain it's a logic error I have somewhere, but can't figure out where I should be looking.

I have a kiosk type application that cycles through a variety of windows, each showing different types of data.  I (presently) control these through a timer, and the application works well, until I finally reach an Out of Memory Exception.

My code to rotate through the windows is as follows:

```
private Window activeWindow;

private void ShowNextTaskWindow(ITask task) {

    Window nextWindow = windowManager.GetWindowForTask(task);

    nextWindow.Show();

    if (activeWindow != null) {
        activeWindow.Close();
    }
    activeWindow = nextWindow;

}
```

The windowManager class simply instantiates the appropriate type of window--that is, a NewsWindow or a VideoWindow, based on the task type:

```
public Window GetWindowForTask(ITask task) {

    Window taskWindow = null;

    switch (task.TaskType) {
            case TaskType.Web:
                taskWindow = new WebWindow(task as WebTask);
                break;

            case TaskType.Rss:
                taskWindow = new RssWindow(task as RssTask);
                break;

     ..... etc ......

    }
    return taskWindow;
}
```

Each window does have (only) one event handler added in the constructor, like this:

```
 Loaded += new RoutedEventHandler(Window_Loaded);
```

and of course, there's an appropriate method called Window_Loaded that does some layout work (setting windows sizing, control sizes, etc).

The problem that I have is that the application simply continues to consume memory until it finally crashed with an Out of Memory exception--and I can't seem to figure out where I'm missing something.

As far as I understand it, calling Window.Close() should get rid of the window, so I'm lost on where to be looking for the problem.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure is not one of the controls in the window which leaks memory? Does the Out Of Memory exception happen if you run your app with empty windows?

Comment: Is your window holding unmanaged resources? Consider using an MVVM design pattern - your current architecture isn't very WPF-styled.

Comment: Much like an answer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2860965/wpf-memory-leak, I have found a case where I did have an event handler with subscribers that wasn't properly dealt with.  This I've fixed--but overall, still suffering from the same problem.   Going to look into MVVM, as I *know* I'm "doing it wrong".  Thanks, @Danny Varod

Comment: Fixed.  There was an event handler that wasn't being removed.  Regardless, completely thrown out and written in MVVM now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should really use [CLR Profiler](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=be2d842b-fdce-4600-8d32-a3cf74fda5e1) to figure out which objects are leaking and eliminate the source of the leak...

But I am also going to recommend that, assuming you are cycling through a small number of ITasks, it might be a good idea to reuse your `Window` instances. In your `GetWindowForTask`, you could use a dictionary (maybe a [ConditionalWeakTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287757.aspx)) to associate Windows with Tasks. If a Task already has a Window, just return it, don't instantiate a new one.

Depending on what's actually going on, reusing Windows might "stop the leak" (although you should still probably figure it out and solve it the right way).

Comment: Yeah, I'm with you on that.  Currently rewriting to MVVM, with the intention of reusing as much as possible.  Hadn't used that tool, though, will try that on the running app. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When you call .Show() on nextWindow it causes activeWindow to be invisible so activeWindow doesn't dispose of it's controls when you call Close().

Close() documentation mentions this scenario explicitly in the Remarks section:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.close.aspx

Comment: Your link refers to winforms while OP uses WPF windows not sure if WPF windows suffer from the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

To find the 'leak' you will have to do some profiling first.

1. Find the window(s) that are causing the leak by testing the program and using just a single type of window. Let the program run until it fails or you are certain that this window type is not causing any problems. Repeat this for all types.
2. After finding the offending Window types examine their code and turn off/on features one by one to find the problem.

Comment: I'm seeing the behavior for all of the window types--it's not limited to a single one.